# Slow time load only in the front page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress Blog. All the sections load good except the home page. The home page is too slow, but I can't find what is slowing it. I search the resources in the console but I don't see any img or script that makes the website takes too long to load.

The site is: https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/

If you go to another section, like https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/casting-gana-con-tu-voz/2019-05-09/ or https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/solidaridad-y-animales-mucho-mas-que-zooterapia/ or https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/solidaridad-y-animales-mucho-mas-que-zooterapia/ you will see that the time is too fast in comparison to the frontpage.

I made the thumbnails smaller but this didn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend having a look at some online tools e.g. [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lagaleramagazine.es%2F&tab=mobile) or [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#5aa6eec150000000)  to get an idea of some of the main things slowing the site down.

Images look like a big part of it, but if you look at the Pingdom waterfall you can see there's a huge delay (wait) before the page actually starts rendering. That to me suggests some pretty intensive php processes, or poor hosting. You might be able to help this a bit with some decent page caching.

Comment: That's the key, the php processes before site starts rendering. I don't know why because the other sections load fine, so it's not a hosting problem.

Comment: It's very difficult to work out what the culprit could be without access to the site. There is a lot going on on the page though. My recommendation would be to set up a staging site and disable various sections (slider, event list etc) and test to see if any one of them makes a major difference. Then at least you've narrowed it down.

Answer (score 0):

Put lazy load post in front page and optimize your css and js and images and html and install cache plugin

Lazy Load example : http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Optimize your Images in Photoshop by saving images as to save for web. Use a browser caching plugin like w3 total cache or wp fastest cache. Enable GZIP compression on your server, gzip option is also available in wp fastest cache plugin. Or add this code in the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Minify Javascript, CSS and HTML files. Don't use too many plugins. Also, use a speed optimized WordPress theme by these ways you can increase your website speed